# Finding CPU utilization in C

Tags: c

I need to calculate the total CPU utilization using C programming.

I tried using /proc/stat and "user" "nice" "system" and "idle", but the result is not the same as with TOP command.

It should be the same as this formula:

```
(total time in second read - total time in first read)/100.
```

Why the result is not matching with top command?

NOTE: I want the total CPU utilization, not for a single process.

Comment: It is operating system specific.

Comment: You can look at the source code for the `top` command here: http://procps.sourceforge.net/

Comment: May be [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) will help?

Answer (score 1):

Similar question, not for C though, is answered in https://serverfault.com/questions/564968/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-the-percentage-cpu-utilization-by-reading-proc-stat

> top uses this file [/proc/stat] for this purpose. But you need to read it more than once.